# Determine convergents for square root

Tags: convergence-divergence, continued-fractions

All square roots can be represented as a continued fraction.
The fraction can be calculated to $n$ terms (e.g. $\sqrt{2}$ is $[1; 2, 2, 2, 2...]$)

So the continued fraction for $\sqrt{2}$ to $3$ terms would be 
$$1 + \frac{1}{2 + \frac{1}{2 + \frac{1}{2 + 1}}}  = \frac{17}{12}.$$

Additionally, the next convergent for square root of $2$ can be calculated with the formula $$\frac{numerator + 2 * denominator}{numerator + denominator}$$
How would I find the simplified continued fraction to $Y$ terms for the square root of $N$? So $f(2, 3)$ would be $\frac{17}{12}$.

If a similar formula to calculating the next convergent of $\sqrt{2}$ exists for all square roots, please include that formula.

Comment: "A square root can be represented as a continued fraction, which can be simplified to the form of x/y." If x and y are integers, then this can't be true.

Comment: It's an approximation. For square root of 2, the following fractions get closer and closer - 1/1, 3/2, 7 / 5, 17 / 12, 41/ 29, and so on. Each one is closer than the last to the square root of 2. I'm asking if there's a formula not just for the square rot of 2, but the square root of X

Comment: Does this help? http://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Sqrt/10/

Comment: That shows the continued fraction. I can already calculate that, I'm just wondering if there's a way to skip the continued fraction and go right to the convergents

Comment: There is a formula for the convergents, but you can't find that formula without finding the continued fraction first. Also, the formula won't be as simple as the one for $\sqrt2$ if the period of the continued fraction exceeds 1; the longer the period, the messier the formula.

Comment: One issue is that there can be several ways to approximate a square root with continued fractions of the generalized form shown in your Question.  To speak of *the* $n$th convergent requires that the continued fraction expansion be uniquely specified, e.g. the [simple continued fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction) where all the numerators are one (not so in your example) and all the denominators are positive integers.

Comment: I apologize for the error. I do mean simple continued fraction. There was an error in the example.

Answer (score 1):

This [tutorial site on *continued fractions*](http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fibonacci/cfINTRO.html#convergrecurr) presents a generalized means of calculating the successive convergents for a *continued fraction* from left to right, each in terms of the numerator and denominators of the previous convergent:

If our continued fraction is [a<sub>0</sub>; a<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>2</sub>, ..., ] then the successive convergents are available (defining *N<sub>-1</sub> ≡ 1* and *D<sub>-1</sub> ≡ 0*) as:

0. C<sub>0</sub> ≡ N<sub>0</sub> / D<sub>0</sub> = a<sub>0</sub> / 1 = a<sub>0</sub>;
1. C<sub>1</sub> ≡ N<sub>1</sub> / D<sub>1</sub> = (a<sub>1</sub>⋅N<sub>0</sub> + N<sub>-1</sub>) / (a<sub>1</sub>⋅D<sub>0</sub> + D<sub>-1</sub>) = (a<sub>1</sub>⋅a<sub>0</sub> + 1) / (a<sub>1</sub>⋅c + 0)

:

n. C<sub>n</sub> ≡ N<sub>n</sub> / D<sub>n</sub> = (a<sub>n</sub>⋅N<sub>n-1</sub> + N<sub>n-2</sub>) / (a<sub>n</sub>⋅D<sub>n-1</sub> + D<sub>n-2</sub>)

For your example of $$\sqrt{2} = [1; (2)]$$ one obtains in succession:

0. a<sub>0</sub>=1; C<sub>0</sub> ≡ 1 / 1 = 1;
1. a<sub>1</sub>=2; C<sub>1</sub> ≡ (2.1 + 1) / (2.1 + 0) = 3 / 2;
2. a<sub>2</sub>=2; C<sub>2</sub> ≡ (2.3 + 1) / (2.2 + 1) = 7 / 5;
3. a<sub>3</sub>=2; C<sub>3</sub> ≡ (2.7 + 3) / (2.5 + 2) = 17 / 12;
4. a<sub>4</sub>=2; C<sub>4</sub> ≡ (2.17 + 7) / (2.12 + 5) = 41 / 29.

Likewise for $$\sqrt{15} = [3; (1, 6)]$$

0. a<sub>0</sub>=3; C<sub>0</sub> ≡ 3 / 1 = 3;
1. a<sub>1</sub>=1; C<sub>1</sub> ≡ (1.3 + 1) / (1.1 + 0) = 4 / 1;
2. a<sub>2</sub>=6; C<sub>2</sub> ≡ (6.4 + 3) / (6.1 + 1) = 27 / 7;
3. a<sub>3</sub>=1; C<sub>3</sub> ≡ (1.27 + 4) / (1.7 + 1) = 31 / 8;
4. a<sub>4</sub>=6; C<sub>4</sub> ≡ (6.31 + 27) / (6.8 + 7) = 213 / 55.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can construct something form

$$\sqrt{a}=1+\sqrt{a}-1=1+\frac{(\sqrt{a}-1)(\sqrt{a}+1)}{1\cdot(\sqrt{a}+1)}$$
$$=1+\frac{a-1}{1+\sqrt{a}}$$

This equation is self referential. So if you plug in the the expression on the right hand side of the equation for $\sqrt{a}$ in the denominator you get.
$$\sqrt{a}=1+\frac{a-1}{1+[1+\frac{a-1}{1+\sqrt{a}}]}=1+\frac{a-1}{2+\frac{a-1}{1+\sqrt{a}}}$$

Now you can repeat this as long as you wish. I hope that was what you were asking for.

And there is a way of directly getting the convergents. Euler did this in a paper.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I think you might have misinterpreted my question. What is the way to directly get the convergents? I can't seem to find it on google.

Comment: Wow! "*Euler did this in a paper.*" is so informative. Euler's collected works comprise over 80 volumes, planned for 84 and in progress since 1911 by the Swiss Academy. Euler produced nearly a paper a week for decades, much of it groundbreaking material that had stumped brilliant minds for decades and centuries before. Perhaps a bit more information could be provided to narrow the search.